# Attached method is called before document.ready

Tags: aurelia

I have an issue with aurelia and materialize bridge dropdowns. The bridge calls a function on a jquery element to enable materialize dropdown widget. At the same time materialize calls the same method to enable the widget on all dropdowns in a document `$('.dropdown-button').dropdown();`

The problem comes when I bundle **and** minify the code with `aurelia-bundler`. `Attached` method on a custom control gets executed earlier than `document.ready` code. Which causes dropdowns to ignore options.

Is there a way to enforce the order of execution in this case?

Comment: Hey, are you sure that this is the problem and not that you may forgot to include the dropdowns to the bundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we discovered with bridge author @Thanood, the solution is to delay setting aurelia root until the document is loaded. This enforces correct methods call order

```
export async function configure(aurelia: au.Aurelia) {
    aurelia
        .use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .plugin("aurelia-materialize-bridge", bridge => bridge.useAll());

    await aurelia.start();
    // this delays loading the root until the document is ready to solve Materialize issue when widgets are initialised twice
    await new Promise(resolve => $(document).ready(() => resolve()));
    aurelia.setRoot("views/root");
}
```